# Count child nodes without counting text-nodes.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I'm loading some html using AJAX, but the html comes with two `div` elements and space between them and `length` counts text-nodes as well.

How can I either dynamically remove the text-nodes between the elements or correct `length` so it does not include text-nodes?

```js
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: submit_url + "/loadmore.php",
    data: {
        load_type: load_type,
        exclude_ids: exclude_ids,
        offset: offset,
        filters: filters
    }
}).done(function (html) {
    var $html = $(html);
    console.log($html);
    offset += $html.length;
});
```

**Example of AJAX Data:**

```html
<div id="post-65" class="g-b g-b--1of1 g-b--sm-1of2 g-b--md-1of4 post-65 guests type-guests status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry hotels-tbilisi">
    <div class="QoutedItem">
        <div class="QoutedItem-content">
            <div class="QoutedItem-overlay"></div>
            <div class="QoutedItem-social">
                <ul class="u-colorGrayLightest lr u-textSize-xs">
                    <li class="u-displayInline u-marginRight-xs">
                        <a href="#" class="Square Square--medium u-borderRounded u-backgroundBlack u-borderWidth-f">
                            <div class="u-posCenter Icon Icon--facebook"></div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="u-displayInline u-marginRight-xs">
                        <a href="#" class="Square Square--medium u-borderRounded u-backgroundBlack u-borderWidth-f">
                            <div class="u-posCenter Icon Icon--twitter"></div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="u-displayInline u-marginRight-xs"></li>
                </ul>
            </div><img src="http://localhost:8000/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/images-3.jpeg" class="QoutedItem-img" /></div>
        <div class="QoutedItem-qoute">
            <div class="QoutedItem-qouteAuthor">Al</div>
            <div class="QoutedItem-qouteText"><p>hey yo</p>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="post-63" class="g-b g-b--1of1 g-b--sm-1of2 g-b--md-1of4 post-63 guests type-guests status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry hotels-kazbegi">
    <div class="QoutedItem">
        <div class="QoutedItem-content">
            <div class="QoutedItem-overlay"></div>
            <div class="QoutedItem-social">
                <ul class="u-colorGrayLightest lr u-textSize-xs">
                    <li class="u-displayInline u-marginRight-xs">
                        <a href="#" class="Square Square--medium u-borderRounded u-backgroundBlack u-borderWidth-f">
                            <div class="u-posCenter Icon Icon--facebook"></div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="u-displayInline u-marginRight-xs">
                        <a href="#" class="Square Square--medium u-borderRounded u-backgroundBlack u-borderWidth-f">
                            <div class="u-posCenter Icon Icon--twitter"></div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="u-displayInline u-marginRight-xs"></li>
                </ul>
            </div><img src="http://localhost:8000/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/images-2.jpeg" class="QoutedItem-img" /></div>
        <div class="QoutedItem-qoute">
            <div class="QoutedItem-qouteAuthor">Dr. ass</div>
            <div class="QoutedItem-qouteText"><p>yep</p>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: what are you doing with the html? displaying it?

Comment: Remove $ sign, it's not necessary here.

Comment: I don't think you're interpreting the results correctly. You're wrapping the HTML in a jQuery object, so `$html.length` will give you the number of DOM elements in the collection. That'll have nothing to do with spaces or newlines.

Comment: In any case its completly unclear what you're trying to do. Why do spaces matter? Why are you keeping track of the "length" of the HTML (which your code isn't doing anyway, as I explained above)?

Comment: @Josh yes I display that.

Comment: @Pointy whitespace becomes a text node element. Thus skewing my calculation.

Comment: @Pointy I'm counting number of items I'm inserting. API sometimes returns 1 div, sometimes 2 sometimes 0. I need to offset it so that consequent call doesn't return same content.

Comment: Oops my comment about jQuery not counting text nodes was incorrect.

Comment: @RomanC why should I remove it? it tells me I've jquery object instead of normal js var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the number of post you can filter by their container

So if you response is like

```
<div class="post">HTTP POST request</div>
<div class="post">New England Post</div>
```

you can use `.filter`

```
var $html = $( html );
offset += $html.filter('div.post').length;
```

this will strip everything that is not div elements with class post from the collection.

Comment: @humble.rumble the point is that it can filter out text nodes by whatever method is appropriate; probably just filtering for `<div>` elements alone will do it, since that's what the top-level elements are.

Comment: @humble.rumble there are many ways to do it,  doing `.not('')` is much less readable though and wont work with some older versions of jQuery.

Comment: I consider most readable would be `var $html = $(html).filter(function (i, element) {return element.nodeName !== '#text'});`

Answer (score 1):

```
offset += $html.replace(' ', '').length;
```

Comment: The value of `$html` is not a string.

Comment: What is the value of $html? At that log

Comment: It's apparently a jQuery object, as it's initialized with `$(html)`.

Comment: @Pointy the type is expected by the `dataType` which has default value

Comment: @RomanC I don't understand what you mean. If the code is retrieving HTML text, then wrapping it in a jQuery object will create DOM elements from the HTML.

Comment: @Pointy You are definitely wrong with your assumptions, show the code that demonstrates what you said.

Comment: Try this: `$("<div/.").length` - what do **you** think that will be?  What do you suppose that call to `$()` in the OP is doing if not turning HTML text into DOM nodes?

Comment: @Pointy I don't understand what are you saying, there's not such code from the OP's question.

Comment: @RomanC     `var $html = $( html );` - it's the very first line of code in that `.done()` callback!

Comment: @Pointy Did you read my comment on the OP's post?

Comment: @RomanC yes - it's incorrect :) The OP *wants* to parse the HTML via jQuery.

Comment: @Pointy I don't care what he wants he said that json should return.

Comment: @RomanC I didn't say anything about returning json :)

Answer (score 0):

Try counting only div elements where id starts with `post-`.

```
.done(function(html) {
  var $html = $(html);
  console.log($html);
  offset += $html.filter('[id^="post-"]').length;
}
```